# jquery slideup not working no matter what I do

Tags: jquery, html

I have a weird issue. Firstly I put the slideup() function into my website and it didn't work. I've tried alsorts to get it to work to no avail. I've even tried a copy and paste of example code into a fresh html file and that doesn't even work. Any ideas? I can always get the click() event to do something, but the slideup() never seems to work. Starting to drive me a little nuts!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>slideUp demo</title>
<style>
div {
background: #3d9a44;
margin: 3px;
width: 80px;
height: 40px;
float: left;
}
</style>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Click me!
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<script>
$( document.body ).click(function() {
if ( $( "div:first" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
$( "div" ).show( "slow" );
} else {
$( "div" ).slideUp();
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6L5yQ/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have more clarity using a class, and gives you the ability for more styling.

eg, something like -

```
if ( $( "div:first" ).hasClass( "visible" ) ) {

  $( "div" ).slideUp().removeClass("visible");

} else {

  $( "div" ).show( "slow" ).addClass("visible");
}
```

You can always try `slideToggle()` too for this kind of job -

```
$( document.body ).click(function() {

  $( "div" ).slideToggle();

});
```

**Demo with the SlideToggle** - http://jsfiddle.net/e7t7F/

**Update, as comment, full page example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Slide Toggle</title>
    <style>
        div { background-color:orange; 
                  display:block; 
                  width:5em; 
                  height:5em; 
                  margin:.5em 
                 }
             /* just example style */
    </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div>ONE</div>
  <div>TWO</div>
  <div>THREE</div>
  <div>FOUR</div>
  <div>FIVE</div>
  <div>SIX</div>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).click(function() {
     $( "div" ).slideToggle();
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, although I must point out that is the example code I copied and pasted, that still doesn't work. Does it work on yours? Also I'm new to jquery :)

Comment: Hi Nick, added a demo of the slideToggle method

Comment: Try also moving the $( document.body ) script under the last closing </html> tag ( just to see , if in fact, you can target the 'body' )

Comment: Hmmm still not working. Can anyone find a simple html page with a working slideup? Something that works so I can see it actually do something, thanks. Sorry this is starting to wind me up ;)

Comment: feel the pain, yes the js fiddle do not show the full context. Updated the answer with full page example - couple of changes to your example - 1) Jquery version is later. 2) 'document.body' is shortened to 'document' - try that. thanks.

Comment: Thanks Rob, Your new example now works! I'm not going to keep this thread going to get every answer to every question, but one more thing. Do you know anyway to make the slideup effect the parent (to the button clicked) and all it's siblings, except for 1 specific div?

Comment: $(".stat_bar_block_title").parent().not(".stat_bar_block_title").slideToggle();

Comment: glad you got this one sorted. It isn't easy to answer the new question in a comment, needs more space and there will be a few ways you can do this. If you open a new question, it will likely get answered very quickly. I'll look out for it.

Comment: Ok thanks Rob. I'll have a bit more of a go at it first, then maybe open a new question later :)